# How to implement nested block correctly ? ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

by this class I send http requests :

```
     @interface AsyncRequest()
        @property(strong,nonatomic)NSURLRequest* murlRequest;
        @property(copy) OnCompleted onCompletedBlock;
        @end
        @implementation AsyncRequest
        //Async Request object initialization
        -(instancetype)initWithUrl:(NSString*)urlRequest onCompletedBlock:(OnCompleted) onCompeletedBlock
        {
            self = [super init];
            if(self)
            {
                //blocks


                NSURL* url  = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSStringstringWithFormat:@"%@%@",SERVER_URL,urlRequest]];

                self.onCompletedBlock = onCompeletedBlock;
                self.murlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
            }
            return self;
        }
    //call this function to execute the specified request
    -(void)ExecuteRequest
    {
        AsyncRequest * __weak weakself = self;

       //localVariable is used by value, a strong reference is made to localVariable in the block
        NSURLRequest *urlRequest = self.murlRequest;
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0),^(void){
            NSURLResponse *response = nil;
            NSError *error = nil;
            NSData * data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest returningResponse:&response error:&error];
                    //main ui
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
                                weakself.onCompletedBlock(data);
                    });
    }
        @end
```

so I declare onComplete block and and initialize them  at `initWithUrlFunction` then I use weakself to run It.

but the problem I get this error at `weakself.onCompletedBlock(data) ->`

> Thread1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=2,address=0xc)

what's the problem ?

Comment: You know that there is a `sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:` method, right?

Comment: yes I know that, but I want to know what's the problem with my code ? and I think gcd is very light weight !so i prefer using gcd rather than using operations

Comment: @david show some code about how are you calling this class? The problem lies there?

Comment: @AsifMujteba ok one minute

Comment: assign `weakself.onCompletedBlock` to a strong var first and test it is not `nil`

Comment: @BryanChen yes that's right! I add this code to ExecuteRequest functin ->OnCompleted onCompletedBlock = weakself.onCompletedBlock and used onCompletedBlock(data) instead of weakself.onCompleted(daata), and it's work fine, thank you very much , please could you explain to me what's the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to assign `weakself.onCompletedBlock` to a strong var first and test it is not `nil` before invoke it.

---

You need to test block is not `nil` before call it unless you can guarantee it cannot be nil. Or your app crashes with poor error message like you had. Unlike invoke method on `nil` object is perfectly safe, invoke a `nil` block will lead to dereference invalid memory address.

`block()` will be compiled to something like `block->someFunction(block->someStruct)` and if `block` is `NULL`/`0`, you get C++ style crash.

---

You don't want to access a `__weak` variable multiple times. You have to assign it to a `__strong` variable then access it. Otherwise it may be released unexpectedly because it is not retained.

```
__weak Foo *obj = // something
[obj dowork];   // obj may be valid value at this point
[obj dootherwork]; // obj may be nil here even previous call success
id foo = obj->somevar;  // may crash with dereference invalid memory address
```

what you need to do is

```
__weak Foo *obj = // something
Foo *strongObj = obj;
if (strongObj) { // not always required
    // you know strongObj is retained and will not be released until it go out of scope
    // so you can access strongObj safely without surprise 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `weakSelf` pattern is not appropriate here. It's used to avoid strong reference cycles, which is not a risk here. In this situation, you just want this `dispatch_async` block retain their constituent objects until the asynchronous blocks execute, so just use `self`.

By the way, if it's possible that this method might ever be called without supplying a completion block, you should ensure it's not `nil`, thus:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
    if (self.onCompletedBlock) {
        self.onCompletedBlock(data);
    }
});
```